# Pagination for list category post plugin

Tags: plugin-list-category-post

This question is about this plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/list-category-posts/

if i do numberposts=10 but i have 20 posts how could i put the pagination there?

this plugin really good but until even the plugin developer has not solve this pagination problem

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Without editing the plugin and/or the author adding a few filters here and there its not going to be possible, but a simple solution can be [using this shortcode](https://gist.github.com/1347400) which does just about the same but with pagination